How to do authorization with FastAPI?
I need to do authorization on FastAPI via a UUID token (9cab9946-1f80-4b71-b03e-95bebebee70235). The token will be issued to the person outside the site. When logging in from a new session, the person will have to confirm the login via the bot's telegram.
So far I've done something like:
class AuthService:
    security = HTTPBearer()

    @staticmethod
    async def get_current_user(
            uow: UOWDep,
            token: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = Depends(security)
    ) -> UserSchemaFromDB:
        user = await UserService().get_one(uow, auth_key=token.credentials)
        if not user:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
                detail="Invalid authentication credentials"
            )
        return user

    @staticmethod
    async def get_current_active_user(user: UserSchemaFromDB = Depends(get_current_user)):
        if not user.is_active:
            # TODO: добавить проверку по сессии, сохранять сессии с которых было разрешено заходить, если вдруг появляется не разрешенная сессия не разрешать заходить
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
                detail="User is not active. Make sure you're logged into telegram first."
            )
        return user


class AuthTokenService:

    @staticmethod
    def generate_token() -> str:
        return str(uuid.uuid4())

    @staticmethod
    async def verify_token(token: str, uow: UOWDep):
        user = await UserService().get_one(uow, token=token)
        if token == user.auth_key:
            return True
        return False

To this code I wanted to add just a router for login and limit only 5 login attempts. If a person enters the wrong value five times, he gets banned from the site.
However, I feels that all this is not very safe and not right. Can you tell me what mistakes I had made and how to better perform this kind of authorization on the site?
